# Values of variables received as null in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have made a simple login app. But the servlet receives null data whenever the form is sent.

Below is login page

```
<body>
<form action="login">
    Enter login Name : <input type="text" name="userName"/><br/>
    Enter password   : <input type="password" name="userPassword"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
</form>
```

The below is the servlet code to check the values of variable entered

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public loginServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = (String)request.getAttribute("userName");
    String password = (String)request.getAttribute("userPassword");

    System.out.print("in doGet method");
    System.out.print(name+" "+password+" are these");


    if(name!=null && password!=null){
        System.out.print("in null method");
        if(name=="admin" && password=="admin"){
//              Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", name);
//              response.addCookie(cookie);
//              RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
//              dispatch.forward(request, response);

            response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("in error method");
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
```

}

I am using System.out.print method to print the values in Tomcat console.

Comment: Move everything from `doGet` to `doPost` and add `method="POST"` to your `<form>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : tried even that. I have edited the statement to 'I am in doGet method', in case that was the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These calls to `Request.getAttribute(String)`

```
String name = (String)request.getAttribute("userName");
String password = (String)request.getAttribute("userPassword");
```

should be calls to [`Request.getParameter(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) (per the Javadoc, that *Returns the value of a request parameter as a `String`*). Like

```
String name = request.getParameter("userName");
String password = request.getParameter("userPassword");
```

Also,

```
if(name=="admin" && password=="admin"){
```

should be something like

```
if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
```

because `String` is an `Object`, and you want equivalent values (not identical references).

Comment: I have converted the object into String, why does it still does not work

Comment: @TinyJaguar because they are request parameters, **not** request attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `request.getAttribute("userName");
 use request.getParameters("username")`;

do it for password also.

Comment: No hard feelings buddy, but did you test your code?

Comment: @Arvind : testing showed no errors, that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your are sending your data via html form, no way you could set the attributes on request, but instead those are parameters. So instead of `request.getAttribute()` try `request.getParameter()`.

Also redirecting to next view using `response.sendRedirect()` is good practice, however if you wish to get previous parameters(user name/ password) on the next view, you are loosing it here. In order to get those details either you can use `RequestDispatcher` or you can continue with `response.sendRedirect()` and use session to take care of the details using `session.setAttribute(<key>, <value>)`.

Comment: The data is sent via form tag in the file sample.jsp